# Reading the xml below shows error in c#

Tags: c#, xml, office-interop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:body>
      <w:customXml w:uri="Sample" w:element="note">
        <w:p w:rsidR="00B06944" w:rsidRDefault="0051608D" w:rsidP="000E0B9F">
          <w:customXml w:element="to">
            <w:r w:rsidR="000E0B9F" w:rsidRPr="00B84BAE">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:bCs/>
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve">Saran </w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:customXml>
        </w:body>
     </w:document>
```

as I want to read the node < w:r >
for this i am writing the below code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("\\document.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/w:body/w:customXml/w:r", namespaceManager);
```

which gives:

> The error shown in this line is Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

How can I read the Xml

Comment: Any reason you're not using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?

Comment: No I have the xml file , What I have to do from that file is to just read all the values node <w:r>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `namespaceManager` about the meaning of the alias `w`. It *sounds* like this is redundant (from the file), but it is **not the case** that the aliases you want for query are *necessarily* those from the source, since the meaning **of the file** is identical if I replace all the `w` aliases in the source document with `foo` (as long as I also define `foo:xmlns` to the be same). Or I could use `xmlns` instead of aliases throughout.

Hence:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.Add("w",
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/w:body/w:customXml/w:r", namespaceManager);
```

This allows your query to succeed identically, regardless of the specific aliases used in the source.

Comment: ye its working but the problem is it does not extracting <w:R> node.

Comment: @user1006544 well, firstly there **is** no `w:R`, since xml is case-sensitive; but as Jon notes the `w:r` is not a child of `w:customXml`, and `w:body` is not the root (a leading `/` means "start at root). You mean *descendants*... which is `/w:document/w:body/w:customXml//w:r`. Or maybe you just mean `//w:customXml/w:r` - only you can tell us

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't give me that error - it gives me an error because the `<w:p>` tag doesn't have a closing tag, and neither does the outer `<w:customXml>`. Once those are fixed, the document *loads* correctly.

There's then the matter of getting the right query. Marc has addressed this in his answer, but personally I'd use the methods in LINQ to XML instead:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
var element = doc.Root.Element(w + "body")
                      .Element(w + "customXml")
                      .Element(w + "p")
                      .Element(w + "customXml")
                      .Element(w + "r");
```

This finds the element correctly. Note that it's not the same as your original XPath even aside from the namespaces - look carefully at your XML; it doesn't have a `<w:r>` element inside the *outer* `<w:customXml>` element.

Answer (score 1):

your xml is not valid. you have no closing w:p tag...

Comment: The fact that it loaded indicated that this is not *actually* the case, and that it is simply an omission from the question.